# How to render countdown function with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to get the countDown() function to run automatically inside render() function, but can't seem to figure it out. Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.countDown = this.countDown.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      count: 5,
      message: ''
    }
  }
  countDown() {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (this.state.count <= 0) {
        clearInterval(this);
        this.setState(() => {
          return {message: "Click here to skip this ad"}
        }) 
      } else {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          return {count: prevState.count - 1}
        }) 
      }
    }, 1000)
  }  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 onLoad={this.countDown}>
          {this.state.message ? this.state.message : this.state.count}
        </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I'm not even sure if this is the optimal way to do it. My goal was to have a 5-second countdown displayed on screen then replace it with the download message/link when the countdown hits zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `componentDidMount` for starting the interval and clear it (to be sure) in `componentWillUnmount` too.

Then use the `this.setState` correctly

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 5,
      message: ''
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.inter = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.state.count <= 0) {
        clearInterval(this.inter);
        this.setState({
          message: 'Click here to skip this ad'
        }); 
      } else {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({count: prevState.count - 1})); 
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.inter);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          {this.state.message ? this.state.message : this.state.count}
        </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to call clearInterval(this.inter) twice?

Comment: If the component unmounts before the count gets to 0, you need to clear the interval

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend calling `countDown` in `componentDidMount` also it is recommended to store the `interval` and clear it anyway in `componentWillUnmount`.

Answer (score 0):

As is your countdown method will run indefinitely as you know is mostly the case with SetIntervals. Also try to avoid using onLoads to call event handlers. What you should do is make use of the component life cycle methods provided by React. Specifically `ComponentDidMount()` and `ComponentDidUpdate()` in your case.

For your countdown, try using something like this

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
    state = {
       counter: 10
    }

//immediately is triggered. This only happens once. And we have it immediately call our countdown
componentDidMount() {
    this.countDown()
}

countDown = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return{
            counter: prevState.counter - 1
        }
    })
}

//will get called everyt time we update the component state
componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.state.counter > 0){
        setTimeout(this.countDown, 1000) //calls the function that updates our component state, thus creating a loop effect
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="time">
            The time is: {this.state.counter}
        </div>
    );
}
```

}