# How can I decrement a state using setState in react javascript

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react js and I'm stuck with this problem. What i want to happen is to output "Hello World" every 10 seconds in the console, and it should output based on the decrementing state in the setState.

For example, I have state numState which is equal to 5 and output "Hello World" after 10 seconds and numState value will become 4 and print again "Hello World" and so on until the numState becomes 0.

Comment: what ? why you need state if you want to print Hello World 5 times

Comment: Please add your code, so that we can have a look at it and help you

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com preferably when explaining an issue put in some code with actual outcome so people can understand what you're trying to achieve. GL on the network

Comment: look at here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018844/how-to-render-countdown-function-with-reactjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` and `setState`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isShow: false,
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.count = 5;
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.count < 1) {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
      } else {
        this.setState({ isShow: true });
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({ isShow: false}), 1000);
        this.count = this.count - 1;
      }
    }, 2000); // you need to change this value to 10000 in your codes.
  }
  render() {
   return (
     <div>
       {this.state.isShow && (
         <div>
           <span>Hello world</span><br/>
           <span>{this.count}</span>
         </div>
       )}
     </div>
   );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></app>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can decrement state value in following way. You should change state value with setState() method only. Because, state value is **immutable** in react

```
this.setState( state => ({numState : state.numState - 1}) )
```

Answer (score 0):

so your state is { numState: 5 }

```
let interval = setInterval(function(){ 

   if(newCount  >= 0 ) {
       this.setState( state =>  ({numState: state.numState - 1}) ); 
       console.log("Hello"); 
    }
  }, 10000);

(() => { if (this.state.numState == 0)  clearInterval(interval ); })();
```